# Why does not cmake find file?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, yocto

I built an sdk using yocto, with dunfell branch.

After installed, there is a problem happening while compilation.
The error occurs when installationpaths.cmake tries to find "artpkg.pc.in", like shown below:

```
CMake Error at /opt/3.2.5.2/sysroots/x86_64-sdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/installationpaths.cmake:25 (message):
  artpkg.pc.in not found!
```

Some prints were inserted in the file to debug the error, the following excerpt show it

```
# Offer the user the choice of overriding the installation directories
if(DEFINED ModuleName)
    set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR lib/lib${ModuleName} CACHE PATH "Installation directory for libraries")
    set(INSTALL_BIN_DIR bin CACHE PATH "Installation directory for executables")
    set(INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR include/${ModuleName} CACHE PATH
      "Installation directory for header files")
else()
    #TODO: Remove else when all applications are using ${ModuleName}
    set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR lib CACHE PATH "Installation directory for libraries")
    set(INSTALL_BIN_DIR bin CACHE PATH "Installation directory for executables")
    set(INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR include CACHE PATH
      "Installation directory for header files")
endif()

#fbs include dir
set(INSTALL_FBS_DIR share/lib${ModuleName} CACHE PATH "Installation directory for fbs include files")
set(INSTALL_PKG_DIR lib/pkgconfig CACHE PATH "Installation directory for pc files")

#Resolve path for artpkg.pc.in
find_path(PKG_IN_FILE artpkg.pc.in HINTS ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

#debug message
message("search path: ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

string(COMPARE EQUAL ${PKG_IN_FILE} "PKG_IN_FILE-NOTFOUND" NOTFOUND)

if(${NOTFOUND})
  message(FATAL_ERROR "artpkg.pc.inc not found!")
else()
  set(PKG_IN_FILE ${PKG_IN_FILE}/artpkg.pc.in)
  message(STATUS "Using pkg template: ${PKG_IN_FILE}")
endif()

# Make relative paths absolute (needed later on)
foreach(p LIB BIN INCLUDE FBS ARTPKG)
  set(var INSTALL_${p}_DIR)
  if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${${var}}")
    set(${var} "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${${var}}")
  endif()
endforeach()

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR INSTALL_LIB_DIR)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}")
```

The result of the debug message is:
`search path: /opt/3.2.5.2/sysroots/x86_64-sdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake`

executing ls in the path, artpkg.pc.in is there:

```
$ ls /opt/3.2.5.2/sysroots/x86_64-sdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake
artbase.cmake      artcppflags.cmake  artflatc.cmake              artinstallmacros.cmake  artprotoc.cmake
artcppcheck.cmake  artdoxygen.cmake   artinstallationpaths.cmake  artpkg.pc.in            artrpath.cmake
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Indeed, it is the search path. However, find_path does not return the path of the file, even though the file is placed there.

Comment: Hint: if you know the relative location to a cmake script file, simply use `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` to get the absolute path of the directory containing the script file, no file search needed. (You probably don't want the file to be taken from another module anyways.) `if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/artpkg.pc.inc")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "artpkg.pc.inc not found!")
else()
  set(PKG_IN_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/artpkg.pc.inc")
  ...
endif()` Btw: a shorter version of the string comparison would be available: `if(PKG_IN_FILE STREQUAL "PKG_IN_FILE-NOTFOUND")`

Comment: @fabian: Even shorter variant of comparison is `if(PKG_IN_FILE)`. CMake treats strings ended on `-NOTFOUND` as false.

Comment: I adopted the solution pointe by @fabian, thank you all for the support.